# RAM Utilization

Tags: java, linux

My question is regarding the RAM Utilization. In our Production Server (Virtual Machine), have 32 GB of RAM and running with only one Java-Tomcat with hazel-cast within application. Please refer below  top command output and RAM utilization for more information.

```
top: 
top - 16:43:59 up 123 days, 8 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 339 total,   1 running, 338 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.1%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32879672k total, 31617688k used,  1261984k free,   513508k buffers
Swap: 16777208k total,    71464k used, 16705744k free,  6933936k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
23410 root      20   0 6214m 1.6g  22m S  0.3  5.1 124:00.66 java
26312 root      20   0  314m  20m 9.8m S  0.3  0.1 135:30.82 gnome-terminal
31009 root      20   0 15164 1436  952 R  0.3  0.0   0:00.02 top
    1 root      20   0 19344 1288 1068 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.72 init


RAM : 
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32109      30876       1232          0        501       6771
-/+ buffers/cache:      23603       8505
Swap:        16383         69      16314
```

The system is consuming 23-24 GB of RAM out of 32 and was configured with JVM of 2 GB. 
My question is why it is consuming that much of RAM. Can anyone help me to get it on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why it is consuming that much of RAM. Can anyone help me to get it on this.

Whenever you read a file, it goes into the disk cache, it stays there until you delete the file or memory pressure causes it to be evicted.  This means that once your machine has read 32 GB of disk space (since booting) you should expect it to have all the memory used for something.

The question you should be asking is why is some memory unused.  Most likely because programs were started and later stopped. Also the OS tries to keep a portion of memory free for sudden memory allocations like starting a program. About 1 - 2 GB free seems reasonable.

In top you can see that 7 GB is for "cached" files and 0.5 GB is for buffers.  Your JVM is using 1.6 GB of resident memory.  The rest is being used by the OS and other programs.

If you want to see a break down of memory use run `less /proc/meminfo`

```
MemTotal:        8077800 kB
MemFree:         2925896 kB
Buffers:          161072 kB
Cached:          2282792 kB
Active:          3714312 kB
Inactive:        1148840 kB
```

Note: that while I am actively using ~ 3.7 GB, a further 2.2 GB is used for caching files.

A trick I use to see how much memory is really being used is to force memory out. e.g.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/deleteme bc=1000000 count=24000
rm /tmp/dleteme
```

This will create a 24 GB file and delete it.  This will show you how much memory is really needed when you run top.  I picked 24 GB as it's about 75% of main memory.